# Question about Position and Momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

This is the question I'm struggling with:

Given

$\left<p|q\right> = \frac{e^{-ipq/h}}{\sqrt{2\pi h}}$

and that

$\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{P^2}}{2m} + V(\hat{Q})$

show that:

$\left<p|\hat{H}(\hat{P}, \hat{Q})|q\right> = \frac{e^{-ipq/h}}{\sqrt{2\pi h}} \cdot H(p,q)$

My working is as follows:

$\left<p|\hat{H}(\hat{P}, \hat{Q})|p\right> = H(p,q)$

$\left<p|\hat{H}(\hat{P}, \hat{Q})|q\right> = \left<p|\hat{H}(\hat{P}, \hat{Q})|p\right> \left<p|q\right>$

$= \frac{e^{-ipq/h}}{\sqrt{2\pi h}} \cdot H(p,q)$

but this is wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try working out the terms $\langle p|\hat p^2/(2m)|q\rangle $ and $\langle p| V(\hat Q)|q\rangle $ one by one. The Ansatz $\langle p| \hat H (\hat P, \hat Q)|p\rangle$ does not help and is not equal to $\langle p| \hat H (\hat P, \hat Q)|q\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\langle p|H|q\rangle &= \left\langle p\left|\frac{P^2}{2m}+V(Q)\right|q\right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle p\left|\frac{P^2}{2m}\right|q\right\rangle 
+ \langle p|V(Q)|q\rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{2m}\langle p|P^2|q\rangle +\langle p|V(Q)|q\rangle \\
&= \frac{p^2}{2m}\langle p|q\rangle +V(q)\langle p|q\rangle \\
&= H(q,p)\cdot  \langle p|q\rangle 
\end{align*}
where we have used :
$$P|p\rangle=p|p\rangle$$
$$Q|q\rangle =q|q\rangle $$